# Что значит T21 в объекте Date?

Tags: javascript

2022-06-18**T21**:00:00.000Z, что значит T21?

Comment: Символ **T** - указатель времени. Подробнее можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:8601:-1:ed-1:v1:en) (смотрите раздел "3.2.5   Designator symbols") или  в [wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Ну и для общего образования https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T21:00:00.000Z - время где 21 значит 9 вечера 00 минут 00 секунд и временная зона

Comment: Спасибо, меня смутило то что я устанавливал часы на 00

Comment: @AlexanderMazovetsky, `Z` - это временная зона `UTC` - скорее всего у тебя временная зона UTC+3